# Count twice data that I get using file get content

Tags: php

I was trying to do one X + X that I got the data from twice different "file get contents" I read that I need to convert it to an "int value" but still not working.

Heres the code

```
$users1 = file_get_contents('firstone/usersOnline');
$users1 = file_get_contents('secondone/usersOnline');
$total = intval($users1 + $users1);
```

Comment: (1) you have `$users1 = ...` && `$users1 = ...` so 2nd will overwrite the 1st. (2) Try `$total = (int)$users1 + (int)$users1;` (assuming you change the 2nd `$users1 = ...` to `$users2 = ...`

Answer (score 0):

You are using same variable name for both values it will overwrite the value . you need to use other name for second value.

```
$users1 = file_get_contents('firstone/usersOnline'); 
$users2 = file_get_contents('secondone/usersOnline'); 
$total = intval($users1 + $users2);
```